# JMeter MVC Login: The required anti-forgery cookie &quot;__RequestVerificationToken&quot; is not present

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have passed the `__RequestVerificationToken` value in login page by capturing it via regex in an MVC login.

However following response is received on executing `JMeter Script`:

The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

**POST data:**

```
__RequestVerificationToken=dZyoPd6T4QmfY-vHSxluKMZcnyNsyxL7rxF2hU5q1Gy8l8- lj9At8Id65CMXrlPxKhUcm8I06B-q_EMRLbLc8vf18FvwNrEPh1f69JqwwgOZs3Duz84d30qlfRBu27un4lx0rQ2&UserName=UserName&Password=PW&RememberMe=I&Button=Log+On&DXScript=1_144%2C1_80%2C1_98%2C1_104%2C14_25%2C14_13%2C1_105%2C1_94%2C1_136%2C1_91%2C14_0%2C1_79%2C14_2%2C1_129%2C1_87%2C14_7%2C1_77%2C1_127%2C1_89%2C1_88%2C14_8%2C1_142%2C1_113%2C1_143%2C1_108%2C14_9%2C1_135%2C1_134%2C1_120%2C14_24%2C1_130%2C1_84%2C1_109%2C1_139%2C1_117%2C1_119%2C14_15%2C1_128%2C1_122%2C14_16%2C14_18%2C1_126%2C1_133%2C1_137%2C14_21%2C14_23%2C1_86%2C5_5%2C5_4%2C4_11%2C4_10%2C4_6%2C4_7%2C4_9%2C14_12%2C4_5%2C1_97%2C1_100%2C4_12%2C4_13%2C1_96%2C1_90%2C1_138%2C1_114%2C14_11%2C1_125%2C1_132%2C7_51%2C1_82%2C7_53%2C14_17%2C1_101%2C1_92%2C14_1%2C1_93%2C14_3%2C1_95%2C1_106%2C14_5%2C1_118%2C1_103%2C14_14%2C1_102%2C1_107%2C10_2%2C10_1%2C10_3%2C10_4%2C14_4%2C9_1%2C9_5%2C14_19%2C9_4%2C8_10%2C8_17%2C8_24%2C8_26%2C8_9%2C8_12%2C8_13%2C8_18%2C14_20%2C8_21%2C8_23%2C8_22%2C8_16%2C8_19%2C8_20%2C8_14%2C8_15%2C8_25%2C8_11%2C6_12%2C14_22&DXMVCEditorsValues=%7B%22UserName%22%3A%22UserName%22%2C%22Password%22%3A%22pw%22%2C%22RememberMe%22%3Anull%7D&Button=
```

Appreciate your input on this!

Answer (score 3):

Your question already has the answer.

`The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.`

Mind the **cookie** bit.

In my previous experience CSRF-protected sites and applications usually send CSRF token as HEADER and expect it to come as COOKIE either "as is" or encoded by some algorithm.

I suggest to try out adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) as a child of the request which is failing and add cookie with the name of `__RequestVerificationToken`, dynamic value which you're obtaining via RegEx and relevant domain and path (the easiest way to determine them is browser + any sniffer, i.e. Firefox + [HTTPFox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/))