# How to pass parameter in Load Testing of a login page with JMeter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, testing, jmeter, load-testing

How to pass parameter in Load Testing of a login page with JMeter and the site developed in asp .net mvc :

[image]

This is what I was trying. But could not manage to find a way where I can find the **_requestVerificationToken** and how to set **RememberMe.**

In the follwoing video, the author used a token from another request may be - when the home page loads may be. But how to set token that time, I didnot understood. [Here is the youtube video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGkrSFKcj10)

**Update:**

I am finally able to send the parameters with value. The http request looks like below:
[image]

**But the response shows following error:**

```
    [HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): The required anti-forgery cookie &quot;__RequestVerificationToken&quot; is not present.]
   System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken, AntiForgeryToken fieldToken) +459
   System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext) +71
   System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate() +92
   System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +18
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass3_1.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +640
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +346
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;BeginExecuteCore&gt;b__152_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +494
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;BeginExecute&gt;b__151_1(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +403
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__20_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +427
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +105
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +163
```

**I am setting the token from the GET call of login page via variable.** And I have checked, the both token in JMeter call are same.

The following StackOverflow question has the same situation. but it did not help me. [Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854117/correlation-issue-in-jmeterthe-required-anti-forgery-form-field-requestverif?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

1. I hope the _requestVerificationToken is being created or in other words its the response of the first login request.If this is the case follow the below steps.

Use Regular expression extractor to fetch the Requestverificationtoken from the previous response. some thing like this

[image]

In this case its license uuid(anyway you cannot use this regex. You have to create your own based on the response you are getting from the previous request. )

and you can use the variable name in the next request where this token is being passed

[image]

Use https://regex101.com/ to find out the regex for your response

2. If _requestVerificationToken is sent in the first login request itself. Then you can just add this value in the parameter field in the http request in jmeter. So one you hard code this value, it will remain for ever. But I doubt that it might get expired in some interval of time. and hence this is a not a good practice to configure in jmeter

Comment: please try the method mentioned in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876757/jmeter-mvc-login-the-required-anti-forgery-cookie-quot-requestverificationto